# The array model is not binding correctly to the view

Tags: angularjs

I'm having problem to make my angularjs app model bind correctly to the view.

I have this methods in the controller to enable/disable the editing of the informations of a single marketplace:

```
$scope.shopEditing = function (marketplaceId) {

    if ( ! $scope.settings) {
        return false;
    }
    return $scope.shopEditingRegistry[marketplaceId];
};



$scope.toggleShopEditing = function (marketplaceId) {

    if ( ! $scope.settings) {
        return;
    }
    $scope.shopEditingRegistry[marketplaceId] = ! $scope.shopEditingRegistry[marketplaceId];
};
```

Then there's the piece of view that should be hidden when the editing for the specific marketplace is enabled:

```
        <div ng-repeat="shopInformations in settings.shops.list">

            <div class="line" ng-hide="{{shopInformations.isShopConnected || shopEditing(shopInformations.marketplaceId)}}">
                {{marketplaceName(shopInformations.marketplaceId)}} shop not connected
                <a class="button buttonGrayThin" ng-click="toggleShopEditing(shopInformations.marketplaceId)">Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when I click on the button that is connected to toggleShopEditing(), the model is updated successfully, the shopEditing() is called correctly, but the view is not refreshed correctly.

The 'div class="line" ' is not being hidden.

I'm getting crazy. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove the `{{ }}` within `ng-hide`

Comment: also may not be related,  the 2nd toggle you might want to return `false` instead of just `return` when $scope.settings isn't set.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you a lot. I've spent 2h and I've not though about it. You saved my eve. Thanks!

Comment: @lucuma why? the toggle shouldn't return the value, it should just toggle. The first method it the one that return the value

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @charlietfl it was enough to remove the {{ }} within ng-hide.